# Verificar dado igual no SQL com onBlur

Tags: php, javascript, formulário, input, onblur

Preciso que ao digitar no *input*, ele verifique no banco de dados se existe um registro igual, como aqueles campos de criação de usuário em email.

Acredito que seja no `onBlur` do *input*, e usar um `if ==` no comando, o problema é: como eu chamo os valores do SQL para comparação?

Sem botão de procurar, tem que ser ao digitar (onblur).

O *input* é limitado em 7 caracteres.

```
<input name="placa" id="placa" type="text" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{4}" size="20" maxlength="7" required onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" onblur="verifExists(digs)">
```

DIV oculta após *input*

```
<div class="style12" id="jaexistedv" style="display:none">Placa j&aacute; registrada!</div>
```

PHP + Java

```
$search_buscar = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['placa'])) {
  $search_buscar = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['placa'] : addslashes($_GET['placa']);
}

mysql_select_db($database_LocalPHP, $LocalPHP);
$query_buscar = sprintf("SELECT * FROM bdsul WHERE bdsul.placa LIKE '%s'", $search_buscar);
$buscar = mysql_query($query_buscar, $LocalPHP) or die(mysql_error());
$row_buscar = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar);
$totalRows_buscar = mysql_num_rows($buscar);

<script type="application/javascript">
        function verifExists(digs) {
        var regpl = <?php echo $row_buscar['placa']; ?>;
        if (digs == regpl) {
            document.getElementById("jaexistedv").style = "display:show";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma chamada Ajax para acessar o banco de dados. Qual linguagem backend vc está usando?

Comment: PHP+Javascript. Não to usando _include/require once_ a não ser o da conexão. CSS + Javascript tudo incluso no próprio documento e não no mesmo lugar, tão espalhados no meio do documento, por exemplo: quando tem um evento em um _select_, o _"application/javascript"_ ta antes.

Answer (score 1):

Usando JQuery e Ajax, você poderia fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
    $("#registro").on("blur", function(){

       var valor = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
          url: "url_da_pagina_backend", // página onde você acessará o banco para fazer a checagem
          data: {
              valor: valor // passa o valor para o backend para checagem
          },
          type: "POST",
          success: function (data) {
              if(data == 'existe'){ // apenas um exemplo de checagem
                  // informe o erro, deixe o campo vermelho, etc.
          }
        }
     });
  });
```

Caso não utilize JQuery, com Javascript puro seria assim:

```
 function checarRegistro() { // Função que voce vai chamar no onBlur do campo
    // Cria um objeto ajax para fazer a requisição
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Pega o valor do campo
    var registro = document.getElementById("registro");
    // Seta tipo de requisição e URL com os parâmetros
    ajax.open("GET", "url_da_pagina_backend/?registro=" + registro, true);
    // Envia a requisição
    ajax.send();
    // Cria um evento para receber o retorno.
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Caso o state seja 4 e o http.status for 200, é porque a requisição deu certo.
   if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
     // Retorno da requisição
     var data = ajax.responseText;
     // Aqui você verifica o retorno e faz a checagem
     if (data == "existe") {
       // faz alguma coisa
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Tenho sérios problemas de entender esse _url_ , tentei procurar a sintaxe no w3schools mas não faço funcionar de jeito nenhum. No caso da página que fiz, não tem uma página de destino de resultado, ele recebe na mesma página.

Comment: Coloca então o código que você já tem na pergunta, pro pessoal analisar melhor.

Comment: Coloquei o que tenho (tem mais de 950 linhas, então separei só o referente ao input e comunicação com o Mysql).

Comment: Certo, então nessa mesma página, no código PHP, você vai ter que criar uma função que recebe via Post o valor que o usuário recebeu no campo (o código que eu coloquei já mostra como enviar o valor). Você faz então um select no banco buscando esse valor, se ele for encontrado é porque já existe, aí você retorna algum valor informando que já existe.

Comment: Eu tava tentando fazer como os _select_ + javascript, onde tenho 3 _div_ no modo _style="display:none"_ e só muda pra _display:show_ quando selecionado. Tava pensando em usar a mesma ideia, deixar um _div_ com _display:none_ e só mudar o `document.getElementById("xxx").style = "display:show";` quando retornar a mensagem dizendo que já existe esse valor no banco de dados. Eu tava tentando transformar a busca em uma variável para comparar com o digitado no _input_ só que me confundi em um monte de coisa no meio do caminho...

Comment: Alterei mais ou menos como tentei usar novamente. Não tenho como usar url, não tem uma nova página, todo resultado fica na mesma página.